# Cloudformation nested stacks by environment

Tags: aws-cloudformation, environment

I'm trying to selectively build some resources depending on the environment. I have 3 Github actions files called `feature-pipeline.yaml`, `dev-pipeline.yaml` and `prod-pipeline.yaml`. I want each to use sam build and deploy commands to build resources from a main `template.yaml` file as well as one of the env specific template files `template-feature.yaml` OR `template-dev.yaml` OR `template-prod.yaml`.

I want to do this because I want my lambdas and api gateway resources to be built similarly across environments but want VPCs and Aurora dbs to be very different in each environment.

How can I structure the output from the main template file while not knowing exactly which nested stack will be built and hence what resources will be built from it?